# cannot find symbol variable

Tags: java

La formulacion del problema seria el siguiente

Una oficina de seguros ha reunido datos concernientes a todos los accidentes de tránsito ocurridos en el área metropolitana de Monterrey en el último año. Por cada conductor involucrado en un accidente se toman los siguientes datos:

- año de nacimiento
- sexo (1: Femenino, 2: Masculino)
- registro del carro (1: Monterrey. 2: Otras ciudades)

a) Porcentaje de conductores menores de 25 años.

b) Porcentaje de conductores del sexo femenino.

c) Porcentaje de conductores masculinos con edades entre 12 y 30 años.

d) Porcentaje de conductores cuyos carros están registrados fuera de Monterrey.

Cuando intento compilar este código

```
import java.io.*;

public class AccidentesDeTransitoEnMonterrey {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int ano_actual, ano_de_nacimiento, edad, registro_del_carro, sexo;
        double a, b, c, d;
        String tecla_repetir;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el valor de ano actual: ");
        ano_actual = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        do {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor de ano de nacimiento: ");
            ano_de_nacimiento = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            System.out.println("Seleccione el valor de sexo.");
            System.out.println("\t1.- Femenino");
            System.out.println("\t2.- Masculino");
            System.out.print("\t: ");
            do {
                sexo = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if (sexo<1||sexo>2)
                    System.out.print("Valor incorrecto. Ingr\u00E9selo nuevamente.: ");
            } while (sexo<1||sexo>2);
            System.out.println("Seleccione el valor de registro del carro.");
            System.out.println("\t1.- Monterrey");
            System.out.println("\t2.- Otras ciudades");
            System.out.print("\t: ");
            do {
                registro_del_carro = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if (registro_del_carro<1||registro_del_carro>2)
                    System.out.print("Valor incorrecto. Ingr\u00E9selo nuevamente.: ");
            } while (registro_del_carro<1||registro_del_carro>2);
            edad=ano_actual-ano_de_nacimiento;
            if(edad<25)
                a=a+1;
            if(sexo==1)
                b=b+1;
            if(sexo==2 && edad>=18 && edad<=25)
            c=c+1;
            if(registro_del_carro==2)
                d=d+1;
            System.out.println("Valor de edad: " + edad);
            System.out.println();
            do {
                System.out.print("\u00BFDesea repetir el proceso? (S/N): ");
                tecla_repetir = in.readLine();
            } while (!tecla_repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("s") && !tecla_repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
        } while (tecla_repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));

        if (n == 0) {
            a = 0;
        } else {
            a=100.0*a/n;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            b = 0;
        } else {
            b=100.0*b/n;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            c = 0;
        } else {
            c=100.0*c/n;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            d = 0;
        } else {
            d=100.0*d/n;
        }
        System.out.println("Valor de a: " + a);
        System.out.println("Valor de b: " + b);
        System.out.println("Valor de c: " + c);
        System.out.println("Valor de d: " + d);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Me sale este error

```
C:\Users\IdeaProjects\Pro\src\AccidentesDeTransitoEnMonterrey.java:54:13
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class AccidentesDeTransitoEnMonterrey
```

Answer (score 3):

El mensaje te indica que Java no encuentra la variable "n", tienes que declararla y asignarle un valor.